# add data to primeng chart

Tags: angular, primeng

this is my code

```
 testing(type: any, month: any, year: any, id: any){
for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++){
  this.nodeService.getDataFromId(type, year , month, id[i]).subscribe(
    data =>{
      var test = data.json()
      for(var j = 0; j < test.length; j++){
        if(test[j].mean == null) {
          this.lineDataDetail.push(0)
        } else {
          this.lineDataDetail.push(test[j].mean)
        }

      }


      this.test.push({
              label: id[this.ids],
              data: this.lineDataDetail,
              fill: false,
              borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
            })

      this.lineDataDetail = []
       this.ids++
    }
  )
}
this.data =  {
 labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14','15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21','22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
 datasets : this.test
}
 }
```

I'm making my own array for the like to use is for the datasets but i keep getting this error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of null** Sorry for the bad english

Comment: to which line is it pointing? `transition` might be because of the `animations`

Comment: this is the whole error massage                                 errors.ts:42 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of null
    at Chart.transition (core.controller.js:526)
    at Chart.draw (core.controller.js:495)
    at Chart.render (core.controller.js:468)
    at Object.helpers.callback (core.helpers.js:967)
    at Object.advance (core.animation.js:127)
    at Object.startDigest (core.animation.js:100)
    at eval (core.animation.js:82)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it ?